# Excel crashes when I copy a cell within a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro that opens a csv file and supposed to copy a cell in the working Workbook:

```
Sub macro1()
Dim build_w As Workbook
Dim build_s As Worksheet
Dim folder_st As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
folder_st = "c:\file.csv"
Set build_w = Application.Workbooks.Open(folder_st)
Set build_s = build_w.Sheets("build")
build_s.Range("A1").Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A284")
build_w.Close True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I comment out the line build_s.Range("A1").Copy everything is fine, but If I leave this in, Excel crashes every single time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From my experience, sometimes non-XLS files, specially large ones, may crash Excel. Sometimes I can solve it saving opened CSV in a XLSX or XLSB format and then work with this new file.

Comment: the CSV file has only 4 cells of data. I'm doing the exactly the same thing in a different macro with a bigger CSV file and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware that the `ActiveSheet` at the moment you paste is itself the `build_s` worksheet? This is the problem when working with stuff like `Activesheet`. It is always preferable to specify worksheet and workbook objects precisely, without counting on what is active at a given moment.

Eventually, to get the behavior you want, you should do:

```
  build_s.Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A284")
```

Comment: I also had to alter the CSV file, I just added some empty lines, that seems to stop from crashing

Comment: @Birbal yes I suspected that the crash was due to some timing issues. Good to know that the problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried handling any possible errors with:

```
On Error GoTo MyHandler

MyHandler:
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because upon opening csv file it becomes the *Active* workbook and its only worksheet the *Active* worksheet

you can exploit this at your advantage like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()
    Dim folder_st As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    folder_st = "c:\file.csv"
    With ActiveSheet '<--| reference your currently active sheet before opening csv file 
       Application.Workbooks.Open(folder_st).Sheets("build").Range("A1").Copy '<--| open csv file (and it becomes the Active Workbook) and reference its "build" sheet range "A1" and copy it...
        .Range("A284").PasteSpecial '<--| paste it to your referenced sheet range A284
        Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| release clipboard
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False '<--| close Active workbook, i.e. the csv file
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

PFB for the require code. CSV file cannot have multiple sheets so that's why it must be crashing. CSV files can have only one sheet in it, so no need to specify sheet name.

```
Sub macro1()

'Declared variables
Dim build_w As Workbook
Dim folder_st As String

'Disabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Initializing the file name
folder_st = "c:\file.csv"

'Opening the workbook
Set build_w = Workbooks.Open(folder_st)

'Copying the value of cell A1
Range("A1").Copy

'Selecting the cell A284
Range("A284").Select

'Pasting the copied value
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Saving the workbook by saving the .CSV file
build_w.Close True

'Enabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: nope, that's not it. I have exactly the same code for a button press with a different csv file and there it works, I don't understand why is crashing for a macro

Comment: As I said CSV file can have only one sheet, so no need to create an object of worksheet. I tried running your code on my system, Macro is not crashing, it is generating an error on line "Set build_s = build_w.Sheets("build")" as by default CSV filename is used as a sheet name for eg here file name is file.CSV so sheet name by default is "file". @Birbal